# How to connect to SimpleSamlphp idp login page (SAML 2.0 p) in asp.net web forms / asp.net mvc service provider (SP initiated)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

Im new to SAML protocol and I need to create an IdP using SimpleSamlPHP which is connected with a local user database. Then I would have to create an SP in asp.net web forms/mvc (preferably asp.net mvc). I managed to setup SimpleSamlPHP as IdP and connect to the local user database with the default saml-sql authentication source/login page. As seen:

[image]

Once the user is logged in, the default SimpleSAMLPhp consumer page is returned. As seen:
[image]

I notice that the login url contains the AuthnState that has the redirect URL. As such:
http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=_6ecd0987b485b771d67a5ddbd62ca4b22913a12fb6%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsimplesaml%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fas_login.php%3FAuthId%3Dsaml-sql%26ReturnTo%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fsimplesaml%252Fmodule.php%252Fcore%252Fauthenticate.php%253Fas%253Dsaml-sql

where: ReturnTo%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fsimplesaml%252Fmodule.php%252Fcore%252Fauthenticate.php%253Fas%253Dsaml-sql

is presumably where the return url is being specified and in which the authnstate is dynamically generated by SimpleSAMPPhp.

With this, I need to create an asp.net webform/MVC (preferably asp.net mvc) project that would be an SP to redirect the user to the simpleSAMLPhp login page page and that would also specify all the parameters found in the AuthnState param including the redirect to consumer page of the asp.net project. I search through the internet and found that WIF does not support SAML protocol and found other frameworks/libraries to test. I am currently trying to implement OneLogin to create an asp.net SP @ https://onelogin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201175694-SAML-Toolkit-for-C-and-ASP-NET and followed the instructions described in the page. I did the following:

1. change configuration in AccountSettings.certificate to match the IdP metadata certificate in SimpleSamlPhp
2. change configuration in AccountSettings.idp_sso_target_url to the SimpleSamlPhp login url as: http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php

When I start the project the login url is generated as: 
http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?**SAMLRequest**=PHNhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCBJRD0iXzU5YTIxN2I0LTg1MGUtNDhiNy05YTU1LWVkMzU3M2U3MzUyNSIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIiBJc3N1ZUluc3RhbnQ9IjIwMTUtMDEtMjFUMDc6MTM6NTlaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpiaW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1QiIEFzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZVVSTD0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0OTU3My9TYW1sQ29uc3VtZXIvQ29uc3VtZS5hc3B4IiB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIj48c2FtbDpJc3N1ZXIgeG1sbnM6c2FtbD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI%2bdGVzdC1hcHA8L3NhbWw6SXNzdWVyPjxzYW1scDpOYW1lSURQb2xpY3kgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDp1bnNwZWNpZmllZCIgQWxsb3dDcmVhdGU9InRydWUiIC8%2bPHNhbWxwOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF1dGhuQ29udGV4dCBDb21wYXJpc29uPSJleGFjdCIgLz48c2FtbDpBdXRobkNvbnRleHRDbGFzc1JlZiB4bWxuczpzYW1sPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YXNzZXJ0aW9uIj51cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YWM6Y2xhc3NlczpQYXNzd29yZFByb3RlY3RlZFRyYW5zcG9ydDwvc2FtbDpBdXRobkNvbnRleHRDbGFzc1JlZj48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3d

which returns as error page in SimpleSamlPHP as:
[image]

I noticed that the generated url by the asp.net SP is not in the same format (filter) as the one generated by the saml-sql SimpleSamlPhp page. like: http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=_6ecd0987b485b771d67a5ddbd62ca4b22913a12fb6%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsimplesaml%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fas_login.php%3FAuthId%3Dsaml-sql%26ReturnTo%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fsimplesaml%252Fmodule.php%252Fcore%252Fauthenticate.php%253Fas%253Dsaml-sql

How does the SimpleSamlPhp login url generated? How do I generate the same url using OneLogin in asp.net? What else do I need to configure or change in OneLogin to match the SP authentication redirect (parameters) required by SimpleSamlPhp? Is there other frameworks that I can use to create an asp.net webforms/mvc (preferably asp.net mvc) SP to connect to the SimpleSamlPhp login page that would also redirect to a consumer page (and read the token) in the .net sp.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a SAML Service Provider implementation for your .NET application. There are plenty of them, OneLogin is one example.

The login url with `?SAMLRequest=PHNhbWx...` looks correct, but trying to decode it in leaves an error. If I use [Kentor's open testing idp](http://stubidp.kentor.se/) with [your payload](http://stubidp.kentor.se/?SAMLRequest=PHNhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCBJRD0iXzU5YTIxN2I0LTg1MGUtNDhiNy05YTU1LWVkMzU3M2U3MzUyNSIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIiBJc3N1ZUluc3RhbnQ9IjIwMTUtMDEtMjFUMDc6MTM6NTlaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpiaW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1QiIEFzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZVVSTD0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0OTU3My9TYW1sQ29uc3VtZXIvQ29uc3VtZS5hc3B4IiB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIj48c2FtbDpJc3N1ZXIgeG1sbnM6c2FtbD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI%2bdGVzdC1hcHA8L3NhbWw6SXNzdWVyPjxzYW1scDpOYW1lSURQb2xpY3kgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDp1bnNwZWNpZmllZCIgQWxsb3dDcmVhdGU9InRydWUiIC8%2bPHNhbWxwOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF1dGhuQ29udGV4dCBDb21wYXJpc29uPSJleGFjdCIgLz48c2FtbDpBdXRobkNvbnRleHRDbGFzc1JlZiB4bWxuczpzYW1sPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YXNzZXJ0aW9uIj51cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YWM6Y2xhc3NlczpQYXNzd29yZFByb3RlY3RlZFRyYW5zcG9ydDwvc2FtbDpBdXRobkNvbnRleHRDbGFzc1JlZj48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3d) a deflate decoding error is reported (The SAMLRequest parameter should be deflate compressed and then BASE64 encoded and finally UrlEncoded).

However I successfully decoded your payload with

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Uri.UnescapeDataString("PHNhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCBJRD0iXzU5YTIxN2I0LTg1MGUtNDhiNy05YTU1LWVkMzU3M2U3MzUyNSIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIiBJc3N1ZUluc3RhbnQ9IjIwMTUtMDEtMjFUMDc6MTM6NTlaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpiaW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1QiIEFzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZVVSTD0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0OTU3My9TYW1sQ29uc3VtZXIvQ29uc3VtZS5hc3B4IiB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIj48c2FtbDpJc3N1ZXIgeG1sbnM6c2FtbD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI%2bdGVzdC1hcHA8L3NhbWw6SXNzdWVyPjxzYW1scDpOYW1lSURQb2xpY3kgRm9ybWF0PSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6bmFtZWlkLWZvcm1hdDp1bnNwZWNpZmllZCIgQWxsb3dDcmVhdGU9InRydWUiIC8%2bPHNhbWxwOlJlcXVlc3RlZEF1dGhuQ29udGV4dCBDb21wYXJpc29uPSJleGFjdCIgLz48c2FtbDpBdXRobkNvbnRleHRDbGFzc1JlZiB4bWxuczpzYW1sPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YXNzZXJ0aW9uIj51cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YWM6Y2xhc3NlczpQYXNzd29yZFByb3RlY3RlZFRyYW5zcG9ydDwvc2FtbDpBdXRobkNvbnRleHRDbGFzc1JlZj48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3d")))
```

which returns

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest ID="_59a217b4-850e-48b7-9a55-ed3573e73525" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-01-21T07:13:59Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:49573/SamlConsumer/Consume.aspx" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">test-app</saml:Issuer><samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified" AllowCreate="true" /><samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact" /><saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

It looks like your SP implementation isn't doing the correct encoding for using a SAML Redirect binding. The encoding used is without the deflate step, which is what is used for the SAML Post binding.

If you have an MVC project I'd recommend a look at the [Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.mvc/) package. Just install it, [configure web.config](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md) and it should work.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Kentor.AuthServices*.